# Why is NSLog causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, selector

I have a tablecell with a button and I want to hook this in to a method call in my main class.

I have it working, but I need to identify the button pressed.  SO I have done the following:

in cellForRowAtIndexPath I do the following:

```
cell.myBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.myBtn addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(viewClick:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And I created the selector method like so:

```
- (void)viewClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running NSLog
    NSLog(@"button row %@",pressedButton.tag);

    if(pressedButton.tag == 1)
    {
       // NSString filename = @"VTS_02_1";
    }
}
```

The problem is I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it hits this line:  `NSLog(@"button row %@",pressedButton.tag);`

Answer (score 4):

specify %i for int value

**you have to use %@ for only object, but int is not object,NSNumber is an object for that you can use %@.**

```
    NSLog(@"button row %i",pressedButton.tag);
```

Comment: omg haha thanks, stupid mistake, i was thinking something was wrong because when i inspected tag it wouldnt show it to me and since this line had the error, I figured it wasnt passing correctly.

Comment: So bad access is caused not just by sending a message to a released object, but also by using a non-object AS an object?  Interesting...  and this answer should have been accepted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try `NSLog(@"button row %d", pressedButton.tag);`

tag property is an int not an object.